# how i get all info about a specific udp open Port using c#

Tags: c#, networking, udp

how i get all info about a specific udp open Port using c#

**example** 
i have udp port `5001` and i want to know how mach data is send or receive in this port
and who is send this data? etc...

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: can u tell me what i need and i well search or tell me the answer because i'm new in network programming

Comment: I would look into packet sniffing. It will allow you to see how much data is being received as well as who sent it.

Comment: For packet-sniffing, you will need a software like wireshark. I don't think there is any System.Net object that lets you do this. For sniffing, you need a direct/previleged access to your NIC, and as per my knowledge only OS and native programs have this ability. You can explore wireshark and see if you can bring it to any uses.

Comment: A quick way to get information about what port is being used by what program is to run the resmon.exe (Resource Monitor) from the run menu. There, in the network tab, you will get all the information you need about your network traffic.